# Bitcoind RPC - create a new address for every payment?

Tags: bitcoin, bitcoind

I'm currently working on a PHP library which will help web developers receiving payments in BTC and other cryptocurrencies.

My question is - should it create a new address for every payment? As far as I know, bitcoind doesn't allow deleting addresses - can it cause troubles when numbers of addresses will go thousands? Or maybe there's a different way to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would generate new addresses for every payment. BUT, the is one other way. You could generate an address for every user, and check if any deposits were made to that address. Personally I prefer to generate an address per transaction though.

Comment: @Xayan Feel free to let me know if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: @Xayan You could always reuse an address after a certain time had passed, a few days would probably be preferable.